# how to wrap drupals taxonomy term node list in a div

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms, nodes

i need to wrap the nodes teaser in a div for my taxonomy term page but cant figure out how.

[this is my page](http://bazarcha.ir/products) , this is a list of nodes for the `products` taxonomy term, using `node--product.tpl.php` i warped the individual node in `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>` but now i need to wrap the list of nodes in `<div class='row'></div>` and just for the `products` taxonomy term page listing ...

how can i do this ???

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to override **page.tpl.php** and wrap the "content" render:

```
      <div class="row">
        <?php print render($page['content']); ?>  
      </div>
```

This will encapsulate your whole **taxonomy-term.tpl.php**, where your node list is.